# Extracting an integer from a runnable and adding it to a LinkedList

Tags: java

I have implemented a server application which uses threads to allow multiple nodes to connect. The server receives the nodes information upon connection. What I want to do is to add the nodes socket to a LinkedList in another class.

Here the code for the node manager:

```
import java.io.*;
import java.net.*;

public class NodeManager extends Thread{

private DatagramSocket socket = null;

public NodeManager() throws IOException {
this("ServerThread");
}

//creates server socket for cmmunication with nodes
public NodeManager(String name) throws IOException {
    socket = new DatagramSocket(3456);  
}

@Override
public void run() {
      while(true){      
        try {

            byte[] buf = new byte[1024];

            // receive request
            DatagramPacket packet = new DatagramPacket(buf, buf.length);
            socket.receive(packet);

           //Get the nodes address
            InetAddress address = packet.getAddress();
           //Get the nodes Port

           //The port int is what i would like to extract and add to a linked list in another class

            int port = packet.getPort();
           //Convert the packets data into a string
            String received = new String(packet.getData(), 0, packet.getLength());

            System.out.println(received);

            //Send message back to node
            String message = "10";
            packet = new DatagramPacket(message.getBytes(), message.getBytes().length, address, port);
            socket.send(packet);

            } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd recommend that you have your class implement `Runnable` rather than extend `Thread`.

You'll have to add a private member to your class and provide a synchronized getter to access it.  Make sure you use a thread safe List implementation (e.g. `CopyOnWriteArrayList`).

Answer (score 0):

That other class has to provide a getter for that LinkedList such that you can get the instance and add the int to it.

Or it has to provide some other methods to add/remove integers to its list.